# C# REST API - returning an array as JSON

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to build a REST API. I have been using this guide by Microsoft Docs and I'd appreciate some help.

I have 2 models Library and Book. Each have their own controllers as well.

I want each to reference each other so I can get all books within a library and I want a book to reference what library it belongs to. I am using an in-memory database by Microsoft Entity Framework

My current model classes look like this:

Library:

```
    public class Library
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public Book[] bookArray { get; set; }
        public string postalCode { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
    }
```

Book:

```
public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public long id { get; set; }
        public long libraryId { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }
```

I want a GET endpoint like so "api/Libraries/{id}/books" that will return the array of books within a library as JSON, but I can't return the array. I get the error "Can't implicitly convert Models.Book to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<A2.Models.Library>". Have I setup the model classes correctly? and how do I resolve this error.

The Code:

```
      // GET: api/Libraries/5/books
        [HttpGet("{id}/books")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Library>> GetLibraryBooks(long id)
        {
            var library = await _context.Libraries.FindAsync(id);

            if (library == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return library.bookArray;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your Method should return `Book[]` like this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}/books")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Book[]>> GetLibraryBooks(long id)
    {
        var library = await _context.Libraries.FindAsync(id);

        if (library == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(library.bookArray);
    }
```

UPDATE

```
public class Library
{
    public Libary(){
         books = new List<Book>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public List<Book> books { get; set; }
    public string postalCode { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
    public class LibraryController : Controller
{
    private readonly LibraryContext _context;

    public LibraryController(LibraryContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost("{id}")]
    public IActionResult AddBookToLibrary([FromRoute]long id ,[FromBody] Book bookToAdd)
    {
        var libraryToAddBook = _context.Libraries.Include(l => l.books)
                                                 .FirstOrDefault(l => l.id == id);

        if (libraryToAddBook == null)
            return NotFound();

        libraryToAddBook.books.Add(bookToAdd);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

UPDATED CONTEXT

```
    public class LibraryContext : DbContext
{
    public LibraryContext(DbContextOptions<LibraryContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Library> Libraries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Library>()
            .OwnsMany<Book>(l => l.books);
    }

}
```

startup.cs

```
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("myDatabaseConnectionString");
        services.AddDbContext<LibraryContext>(options =>
        {
            //options.USEYOURDATABASE(connectionString); //you might need install a NuGet eg. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
        });
```

Comment: Ive forgot the Ok() ive added it to the answer

Comment: Wow, so bummed didn't notice that. Thanks! Are my models set up correctly?

Comment: Ive updated the model. I prefere lists because you can easy .Add(someBook) to your library its important to then initialize the list in an empty constructor

Comment: In your modelCreating, are you setting up a library to have only one book instance? I want a book to be able to belong in one library and a library can have multiple books. You've helped alot as it is, may I ask if you break down the code for me? How would I add a book to a llibrary from a post request  (adding a book to a particular library). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ive updated the code sinppets i hope its clear to you

Comment: For some reason when I try to return the array I just get an empty array. The book is added to the DbContext as well as the list in the code. When performing a simple get on Books, the book shows up. But for some reason when I do get ...{id}/books (getLibraryBooks) I just get an empty array. I even tried using "return library.bookarray.toArray()"

Comment: when loading the books from context try _context.Libraries.Include(l => l.books).FirstOrDefault(l => l.id == id);

Comment: It works! thanks! with all your help I have been able to add libraries and books via post and get them as well. I have one final question, that is how do I read the request headers? I want to read for a key say "sorted" and if it is true I return a sorted version of all the books. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.headers?view=netframework-4.8 ddoesn't seem to work

Comment: You shouldn't go with evaluating a header for this case. If its in your hand add a query parameter with a default to false